# I want to set up a form that will send its input data to a database. But I have no idea where to start

Tags: php, database

This is for a school project.

I have a website. I want this [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTgBS.jpg)  to send its data into a database, but I have no idea where to start.

I want each field (Title, Name, Email, Inquiry) to be sent to an accessible database where the data is stored.

This is the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh3rZ.jpg)  I have for the form. As you can see I have a "demo.php" page its linked to but that is empty. It's from a YouTube tutorial that I struggled to follow.

I understand that some level of PHP is involved to achieve this, so I have left it in. Is there anybody that could provide me with a basic guide on how to get around this? Treat me like a 5 year old, as this stuff really confuses me.

Comment: You will need to add information about what type of database you are using, what your web server is and anything else about your environment that someone might need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the link.It will explain the whole process of form submission & save in database:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to continue watching videos if that is how you learn best, thenewboston has pretty good videos for beginners. To do what you want you will need to create a database and a file that handles the data before completing a database query which would insert the data.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL442FA2C127377F07